# Scala AST Select vs Apply

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros

I'm confused over when a select is appropriate and when an apply is. I thought apply was a function or method application, thus

```
scala> val expr = u reify { Random.nextInt }
expr: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Int] = Expr[Int](Random.nextInt())

scala> u showRaw expr.tree
res0: String = Apply(Select(Ident(scala.util.Random), newTermName("nextInt")), List())
```

Is what I expect; an application of nextInt with an empty parameter list.

Also,

```
scala> val expr = u reify { Random.shuffle(List("sammy", "snake")) }
expr: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[String]] = Expr[List[String]](Random.shuffle(List.apply("sammy", "snake"))(List.canBuildFrom))

scala> u showRaw expr.tree
res2: String = Apply(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.util.Random), newTermName("shuffle")), List(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant("sammy")), Literal(Constant("snake")))))), List(Select(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("canBuildFrom"))))
```

Is again what I expected - an application of the shuffle method, with a list of strings.

However,

```
scala> val expr = u reify { Random.shuffle(List("sammy", "snake")).head }
expr: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[String] = Expr[String](Random.shuffle(List.apply("sammy", "snake"))(List.canBuildFrom).head)

scala> u showRaw expr.tree
res1: String = Select(Apply(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.util.Random), newTermName("shuffle")), List(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant("sammy")), Literal(Constant("snake")))))), List(Select(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("canBuildFrom")))), newTermName("head"))
```

Is a Select on head. I'm confused because I would have thought that that outer node would be an application of head. Why is it a select when head is a method?

Is there a web page that details the difference between Select and Apply because I cannot find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of `Select` and `Apply` is purely syntactical.

`Select(prefix, newTermName("member"))` means `prefix.member`

`Apply(prefix, List(arg1, arg2, ...))` means `prefix(arg1, arg2, ...)`

So techically, `Random.nextInt` is a `Select`, but the Scala typechecker wrapped it in an additional `Apply` because `Random.nextInt` is defined as a function that takes single, empty parameter list. In other words, this is a desugaring performed by the typechecker.

This isn't the case with `List`'s `head` method. If you look at its definition, it takes *no* parameter lists:

```
def head: A
```

And that's why the typechecker does not wrap it in an `Apply` tree.

Summarizing - there is difference between methods that take single, empty parameter list and methods that take no parameter lists. As a syntactic sugar, Scala allows to call methods with single, empty parameter list as if they take no parameter lists (without any parens), but the typechecker will still add the `Apply` in such cases.

Comment: You beat me by 25 seconds! :)

Comment: I can't select you both as accepted answer so I literally tossed a coin between this and @eugene's answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case, trees precisely reproduce syntactic structure of Scala programs. `Select` corresponds to member selection, e.g. to `foo.bar`, whereas `Apply` stands for an application of an argument list, e.g. `baz(1, 2, 3)`.

If we have an empty arglist method in Scala, e.g. `def x() = ???` (or `Random.nextInt()`), then its invocation can be written both as a `Select` (corresponding to `something.x`) and an `Apply(Select(...), Nil)` (corresponding to `something.x()`), because both are valid Scala expressions.

If we have a nullary method in Scala, e.g. `def y = ???` (or `List.head`), then its invocation can only be written as a `Select` (which corresponds to `somethingElse.y`). If we write `Apply(Select(...), Nil)`, that would mean `somethingElse.y()`, which would stand for applying an empty argument list to the result of calling method `y` on `somethingElse`.

Comment: I can't select you both as accepted answer so I literally tossed a coin between this and @ghik's answer